# What is your opinion about send POST and GET together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have edit company form (company it's example).
I create form like this:

```
@using(Html.Beginform("Edit", "Company", new { id = Model.Id }, HttpMethod.Post))
{
    Html.EditFor(_ => _.Name);
}
```

But my сolleges

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
    Html.HiddenFor(_ => _.Id);
    Html.EditFor(_ => _.Name);
}
```

I not have a strong opinion. How to explain to my colleges this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. A request can either be a GET or a POST, not both.

Comment: My form submitted by POST with GET information in URL. My colleges are not like this.  His says "if it's POST we must use ONLY post information"

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: What did they exactly say was wrong with this?

Comment: They don't have strong opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A form can use POST or GET. Most forms will use POST.

And you choose one or the other, and should not try to use a combination of the two. It's a verb - you're either GET(ting) or you are POST(ing).

Answer (score 0):

The request by GET sends the form data in the URL. The POST request sends form data in the body of the request.

If you want in a POST request, you can send data in the URL by adding these data to the URL action in the attribute `action` in the form. You decide whether it makes sense or not, it all depends on what type of data is to be sent.

In the forms of adding and editing it is best to send all data via POST, and in some cases the field ID is sent encrypted to prevent manipulate by the user. In my opinion and in this case it doesn't make sense data by POST and add field ID in querystring.